# Windows 7 network keeps failing

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7

So I have a really strange and enervating problem:

My network card periodically just stops working and the only thing I can do to make it work again is to restart the computer or uninstall the driver from the device manager, and then scan for hardware changes, which reinstalls the same driver and it starts working again for a few hours or minutes.

- When it goes out, on the taskbar it
  says that the cable is unplugged,
  which is untrue.
- When I try enabling/disabling the network adapter, the enable doesn't work it stays disabled.
- When I try enabling/disabling the network adapter in the device manager after enabling it says that driver failed to load

hardware & specs: Windows 7 Professional x64, ASUS M4A79XTD EVO motherboard, Realtek RTL8112L NIC.

I have latest bios, latest drivers for everything, I tried latest driver from asus, latest from windows update and latest from realtek site for the network card but all fail the same.

Any help on finding out what exactly is wrong would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a different network card?

Comment: well not really an option for me unless it turns out that I can't fix this one and then I might buy a separate network card

Comment: I think Randolph was suggesting that you could borrow a known good network card from another computer.  It would be worth a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try hard setting the speed and duplex on either the NIC or switch. Auto-detect incompatibilities between manufacturers and sometimes even across product lines do occur.

Comment: I have set it to 100 mbps full duplex now, gonna wait and see if it happens again or not. Also it does drop the connection on 3 different routers.

Comment: nope, unfortunately it didn't fix the problem :|

Comment: Then you have a hardware issue that may be interrupt related or just faulty hardware. Before writing things off as faulty hardware, you might try repositioning the NIC into a different bus slot, if available/possible.

Comment: Yeah seems so, since I didn't really found anyone else with the same problem on the same motherboard, and no I can't switch the card since it's an onboard one. Well at least network adapters are cheap..

Comment: Since it is an on-board, you might consider moving around any other cards, if there are any populated.

Comment: there's nothing in pci slots only the gfx card :-/

Comment: Last ditch attempt would be to see if the interrupts can be moved around between the assigned devices or BIOS assignments...

Comment: just bought a different pci lan card and it seems to work with this one, no more disconnects since a couple of hours. I'll leave it at that. 

Too bad that I've spent more on a better motherboard and issues like these still come up.

Thanks for your help though!

Comment: That's too bad it wasn't a simple fix. Maybe there is a chance that the motherboard is under warranty...